# Discount code shows in cart but not checkout Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, promotions

We have a cart price rule that applies a discount to a certain product *(e.g. if item found in cart with brand 'Nike' then discount 'Nike' product 10%*).

- A customer goes to `checkout/cart/` the discount shows OK.
- A customer moves to `checkout/#shipping` the discount no longer shows.
- A customer moves to `checkout/#payment` the discounts shows OK.

It's confusing for customers not to see the same basket value all the way through the process.

Is there a way to resolve this issue? And ensure **product price with discount is visible in the same way on the #shipping page**?

Comment: Have you checked the same thing in the default Magento? If it is working in default Magento then it can be an issue with your custom theme or custom module. Please check in the default Magento setup.

Comment: Checked Nits and yes - seems to be standard Magento functionality - as same happens in Luma theme.